# Why does the text of the label does not change?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

So I started to code in windows forms and im trying to make a simple game.
I created a label of score, and I want that it will be updated if something happens.

I thought that I just need to right the if statement in the runing form code with label.Text after I convert an int variable to string.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (objPos == Position.Up)
        {
            y -= 50;
            if (objSide == Side.Right)
                x += spd;
            else
                x -= spd;
        }
        else if (objPos == Position.Down)
        {
            y += 50;
            if (objSide == Side.Right)
                x += spd;
            else
                x -= spd;
        }
        if (y <= 0)
            y = 0;
        else if (y >= 553 - 80)
            y = 553 - 80;

         if (x >= 1250)
        {  
            x -= spd;
            objSide = Side.Left;
        }
        else if (x <= 0)
        {
            x += spd;
            objSide = Side.Right;
        }
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(x, y, 40, 40);

        if (r2.IntersectsWith(ln3.Bounds) | r2.IntersectsWith(ln4.Bounds) | r2.IntersectsWith(ln5.Bounds) | r2.IntersectsWith(bb1.Bounds) | r2.IntersectsWith(bb2.Bounds) | r2.IntersectsWith(bb3.Bounds)| r2.IntersectsWith(bb4.Bounds))
        {
            tmrMoving.Stop();
            EndGame End = new EndGame();
            End.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        if (x == 1250 )
        {
            spd += 50;
            score++;
            string s= Convert.ToString(score);
            Score.Text = s;
            Score.Refresh();

        }
        Invalidate();
    }
```

This code is in the Form.cs of the form of the running game.There are some more if statements in it,changing the position of an object so I expected this to work but it doesn't. How should I do it then?
Edit: Posted some additional code.If someone knows how can I create an array of picture boxes so I can use IntersectsWith more effectively it will be nice.

Comment: Try Score.Refresh();

Comment: Did you step through with the debugger? Does Score.Text = s execute?

Comment: Did you set a BreakPoint on the `if (x == 1250 )` condtiion to see whether that condition is ever met? There's the chance you never actually assign a value to that Label. Also, where did you put this code? The context is missing.

Comment: Is that code running in a loop?  If so, the gui doesn't have a chance to refresh itself.

Comment: You should post additional code, It's not clear where your problem lies, if your code where in a simple button_click method It would update the label.

Comment: @Jimi I know the condition is met because I have another if statement with this condition.

Comment: @SlavenTojic The code does not lay in a simple button.click.But what additional code do you want me to post? From the same function?

Comment: @LarsTech No it doesn't run in a loop.

Comment: @Jimi But the other if statement changes something and it works..

Comment: @LarsTech The code is in a timer1_Tick should I post additional code from it?

Comment: As posted, this code should work (assuming those missing semi-colons are really there). This is a debugging problem we can't solve for you.

Comment: If `Score.Update()` does not works, you can always update the entire form, like `this.Update()`